# ¿Por qué NaN != NaN?

Tags: javascript

Tenía tiempo programando en JavaScript y nunca me había dado cuenta de esa peculiaridad que tiene con el valor `NaN`.

Decidí investigar y lo más que encontré fue: [NaN - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NaN) / [[inglés]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

Entendí que `NaN` es la referencia de «Not a Number» (no es un número) pero no me quedo claro el por que un NaN no es igual a otro NaN utilizando el operador `==`, `===`.

```
parseFloat('NaN') == parseFloat('NaN'); // false
parseFloat('NaN') == NaN; // false
NaN == NaN; // false
```

¿Qué ocurre a nivel lógico que la igualdad no se cumple?, ¿por que no aplica también para la expresión `undefined == undefined`?

Comment: Esto no es una peculiaridad de JavaScript, es así en cualquier idioma que conforme al estándar IEE754 (sobre la representación de números de coma flotante).

Comment: Lo que sí se cumple, y creo que está documentado en algún sitio, es que `NaN + NaN + NaN + NaN + NaN + NaN + NaN + NaN + NaN = "Batman"`

Comment: Está documentado aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4603/por-qu%C3%A9-nan-nan#comment8434_4603

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Así es como ha sido definido y tiene sentido, por ejemplo imagina el siguiente caso:

```js
var a = 1/"lunes"; //NaN
var b = Math.sqrt(-1) //NaN
```

Tanto `a` como `b` dan como resultado `NaN`. Ahora, ¿te parece correcto que sean iguales?

Es por esto que se usa la función `isNaN()` para verificar si estamos ante un `NaN` o no en vez de intentar compararlo contra otro `NaN`.

Esto no se aplica a `undefined` porque este tiene un significado preciso: Un identificador no definido. En cambio `NaN` es una suerte de valor inválido para lo que en otros lenguajes sería un error en tiempo de ejecución o excepción.

Comment: En tu respuesta, tal como mencionas; no me parece correcto que `1/"lunes"` sea igual a `Math.sqrt(-1)`. Porque el primero es algo *indeterminado*, mientras el segundo es un *número complejo*. Pero no me parece algo obvio cuando pregunto por `Math.sqrt(-1) == Math.sqrt(-1)` ya que se debería tratar del mismo número complejo. Tampoco por `1/undefined == 1/undefined`.

Comment: Pero los números complejos no existen en Javascript. Míralo de esta forma, el resultado de la operación ya no es un number y los operadores ==  y != simplemente no están definidos de igual manera que para los numbers. Además cual es la diferencia entre un NaN y otro NaN? Es como preguntar cual es la diferencia entre un 1 y otro 1?

Comment: Citando: "cual es la diferencia entre un NaN y otro NaN? Es como preguntar cual es la diferencia entre un 1 y otro 1?" Esa era la duda planteada, si no hay diferencia; `1 == 1` **debería** ser `NaN == NaN`. Actualmente para entender la decisión que tomaron, interpreto que 1 está definido, es el número 1 partícularmente. La definición de NaN en cambio **es un conjunto** de valores: cualquier cosa, excepto un número. Y bueno, como es un valor primitivo, no contiene propiedad para saber de qué operación se origina al comprobar 2 NaN, entonces directamente se los considera diferentes.

Comment: Me refería a que si `1/"lunes` da `NaN` y `Math.sqrt(-1)` da `NaN` como podrías diferenciar entre esos dos `NaN`? Para ser esto posible no deberían dar NaN, sino dos resultados diferentes an ambos casos. JavaScript es un lenguaje que tiene definiciones que van contra el sentido común. No por esto quiere decir que sean menos o mas correctas. Lo más adecuado como mencione anteriormente hubiera sido que dichas operaciones lancen un error, en lugar de devolver un valor.

Answer (score 6):

En palabras simples `NaN Not a Number` (NaN No es un número) y como no es un número, es cualquier cosa. No es posible comparar cualquier cosa de un lado con cualquier cosa en el otro lado, por lo que nada garantiza que ambos son iguales. Por ejemplo no es posible hacer esta comparación:

```
(0.0 / 0.0) == (0.0 / 0.0)  // false
```

Esta comparación es lo mismo que:

```
NaN == NaN; // false
```

En JavaScript `undefined` es un **tipo de dato**, al igual que lo son el `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Object` o el `Array`. En JavaScript , a diferencia de otros lenguajes de programación con fuerte tipado, podemos tener variables de tipo `undefined`.

En resumen, en JavaScript , todas aquellas variables que no han sido definidas (por lo tanto, no existen) o que han sido definidas sin asignarles un valor, son siempre de tipo `undefined`.

Por lo que lógicamente al comparar dos cosas que tiene el mismo **tipo de dato**, en este caso `undefined`, retorna `Verdadero`.

Referencia: [Java Language Specification (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/typesValues.html)

Answer (score 4):

Revisando la documentacion
[NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NaN)

Veras que comenta

> NaN nunca es equivalente con cualquier otro número, incluido el mismo NaN; no puedes chequear el valor de un not-a-number comparándolo con Number.NaN. Usar la función isNaN() para aquello.

O sea debes usar el `isNaN()` para lograr lo que planteas.

Quiero pensar que esto es asi porque se trata de un objeto, el cual se compara por referencia al usar el `==` poreso dos referencias no seran iguales.

No sucede lo mismo con 
[undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/undefined)
porque este es un valor primitivo, no es un objeto como NaN, por eso puedes compararlo con el igual.

Comment: ´NaN´ no es un objeto. Es un valor primitivo. No son iguales porque se decidió que no lo sean. La pregunta básicamente es: ¿Cual fue la lógica para tomar esa decisión?.